# Can't Toggle Static declarativeNetRequest Static Rules

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, adblock, webfiltering, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I see that Google [wants Chrome Extension developers to migrate](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#modifying-network-requests) from [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest) to [`chrome.declarativeNetRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest). I see [static rules](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#rules), but the trouble there is that how do we allow a user to toggle individual rules on or off per website? Most users want whitelisting overrides. This is why we used `chrome.webRequest` to look at network connections on any given web page, and if any of those URLs matched a regexp ruleset, we could deny the request, and that Javascript could look to see if the user wanted to toggle that off on a given website to whitelist it.

Is there a way with `declarativeNetRequest` to look at any website and load in static rules that a user could toggle off (whitelist) for a given website if they desire from their options panel?

Comment: Not implemented: https://crbug.com/1225229. Could you elaborate on the problem with using the dynamic rules?

Comment: Edited. Changed "dynamic" to "static". So, let's say we have example.com as the website the user browses to, and on it a script from evil.com to block in a static rule. But a user says no, they want to prevent all the static rules from running on example.com, allowing evil.com to run. He might have a panel with an enabled/disabled toggle. How, in code, do we turn off the static rules on example.com for this user, yet block the evil.com script on other websites he browses to?

Comment: You'll have to use dynamic rules. Or add a new dynamic rule that overrides the "disabled" static one.

Comment: When the user browses to example.com (`chrome.tabs` API check) and he's whitelisted this domain, would I be using `chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateEnabledRulesets`  to disable ruleset id 1? Or does that disable it for all tabs?

Comment: I guess you would use updateDynamicRules and supply tabId.